# STM32F4xx Description of IRQ handlers in the stm32f4xx.c file

Tags: microcontroller, interrupt, stm32, interrupt-handling, stm32f4

I am searching for the description of the `IRQ-Handlers`, which are defined in the `stm32f4xx.c` file. I can't find any description of them.

For example:

```
void WEAK  CAN1_TX_IRQHandler(void);    
void WEAK  CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler(void);    
void WEAK  CAN1_RX1_IRQHandler(void);    
void WEAK  CAN1_SCE_IRQHandler(void);
```

Ok, some of them are clear, but where can I find the information, what `CAN1_SCE` means and under which conditions they occur?

Could anyone help me to find the description of the handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference manual, CAN interrupts. For every interrupt source there is a handler.

[image]

It is **Status Change Error Interrupt**.

> The error and status change interrupt can be generated by the following events:
>
> - Error condition, for more details on error conditions please refer to the CAN Error Status register (CAN_ESR).
> - Wakeup condition, SOF monitored on the CAN Rx signal.
> - Entry into Sleep mode